# SSH using one port(client) to another port(server)

Tags: ssh, port

I'm in a college. My college blocks all the ports except 80 and 443. My ssh server runs at the default port. So is there anyway that I can access my ssh server from my college.

I badly need a method. 
I was thinking if it was possible to set an outgoing port in the client side during ssh that  connects to the server in a different port.

Is it possible, and is there any open source softwares that allows this, or is it possible to write a socket program that can do this feature.

Comment: If there is a legitimate academic need for it, the exception should be granted.  otherwise, you shouldn't be misappropriating University resources, so go buy a 3G dongle and use that for your personal projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the ssh client to use a different port with the `-p` command-line option:

```
ssh -p 443 your.remote.host
```

You can tell the ssh server to listen on a different port using either the `-p` command-line option or the `ListenAddress` directive in your sshd configuration file.

Comment: My question is that .... I cannot do that. I bought a hosting service that provides me ssh access. They cannot change the ssh port.

Comment: If you have no control over the server, then you're out of luck.  You could set up another system (e.g, at your house) providing ssh service on either port 80 or 443 and use that as an intermediate point...but as womble said, if you have a legitimate need for the exception, contact the appropriate folks in your local organization.

Comment: You could also investigate [ShellInABox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/), which provides console access via your web browser.  But again, this may require more control over your remote server than you appear to have.

Answer (score 1):

you can either configure ssh to listen on the SSL port or alternatively, use NAPT to tranlate the port from 443 to 22.

However, you would have far greater flexibility if you used that port 443 for opening a VPN tunnel into your host (OpenVPN would work for this).